# Argparse and command line syntax

Tags: python, argparse

I'm writing a program that takes a file argument like `*.xml` or `*.txt` or something like that. For example:

```
parser.add_argument("-f", "--file")
args=parser.parse_args()
```

e.g.

```
python myprog.py -f *.xml
```

Then `args.file` would not give the command line string `*.xml`, but rather the directory listing than conforms to `*.xml`, but that is not the behavior I want.

So here is my Question: Is there a way to get the `*.xml as a string. I know that you can enter

```
python myprog.py -f '*.xml'
```

but for a lot of different users this will not work, as some will forget the `'`.

In other words, I need the original text that was entered in the command line.

Comment: That's the behaviour of your terminal, **not** of Python. Try `python myprog.py -f "*.xml"`

Comment: Why don't you want to use your shell in the correct way? Teach your users about how the shell expands wildcards.

Comment: *"but for a lot of different users this will not work, as some will forget the '."* - I think the best you can do about that is check whether the input you got was in the form `*.something` and throw an error *"remember you have to quote or escape wildcards"*. You could even try to figure out what they actually meant by looking at the common part of the directory listing!

Comment: How about asking for a different string, something like 'all', or 'all_xml'.  Or maybe a `--suffix xml` argument that you tanslate to `*.xml`.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that the shell is expanding the `*` before it gets to python or argparse.  Try escaping it so the shell won't process it like

```
python myprog.py -f \*.xml
```

Answer (score 4):

The `*` character is used by shells to expand pathnames. As you've already found out, to prevent this you must quote it:

`python myprog.py -f '*.xml'`

If you'd like to avoid the need of quoting, you could use some other syntax, e.g. SQL-like:

`python myprog.py -f %.xml`

Comment: He already does this but he doesn't like it. Well, that is tough luck :)

Comment: How about getting the last entry from the command line history? Any ideas how to to that quickly? Any other ideas to circumvent this problem?

Comment: @Peter: this depends on the shell/version. Perhaps, ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, it's the shell that does filename expansion, before python is even invoked.

If it's the sort of program that you often use several times in succession, then the best you can do to avoid the "problem" is having the program prompt for a command, either always, or if a command is not passed to its primary invocation.

```
$ python myprog.py
myprog> -f *.xml   # prompt from python and "-f *.xml" read without any interference
myprog> exit # or your system's end-of-file, control/D on linux.
```

as an alternative to

```
$ python myprog.py -f \*.xml
```

This is most natural with a program that is commonly used repeatedly or interactively. For example, `psql` (the console interface to the Postgres DBM)

```
$ psql [global options] -c command 1
$
$ psql [global options]
psql> command 1 ;
psql> command 2 ;
```